# Azure functions proxy ignored

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I have a simple function app with proxy setup. Somehow, I'm getting a message below when function is executed. I can see this message both locally and via Kudu. As result, all I get back is 404 error when send request to my app. I'm on Runtime version: 2.0.11651.0 (beta). Does anyone know what this error is trying to tell me?

[Warning] LibDir is null or empty, proxies.json will be ignored

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxies are not supported in that build yet. The supported version is 
2.0.11776 or higher. This version is being deployed as we speak and should be everywhere within a week or so.

Comment: Thank you. All I did just followed online tutorial. Looks like this time documentation is running ahead of release schedule.